# Unable to send app invitation to facebook friends

Tags: iphone, facebook, invitation

When i send invitation to friends, friends receive that invitation but nothing has opened. When user get invitation and click the url is made which is given below -

https://apps.facebook.com/invitationitesting/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=528827943820609&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_invite

this is not working now this url is same as url :-

https://apps.facebook.com/farmville-two/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=119410701597152&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_invite

I think i forgot some formalities in app setting. Please help me to solve this problem .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below link its describe the step-by-step process.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/

Hope its usefull for you